# How to update uniqueidentifier (GUID) from nvarchar in SQL Server (GUID with no dashes)

Tags: sql-server

Cannot update uniqueidentifier field without dashes

```
update a
set GUID =  replace(b.guid,'-','')
from table1 a 
join table2 b on a.ID=b.ID
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 26
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

The GUID in table1 must be in "no dashes format"

```
e1336903e4d04d2a88ad23ed87ddfff0
```

The GUID in tabl2 is

```
E1336903-E4D0-4D2A-88AD-23ED87DDFFF0
```

I have tried casting to `varchar(36)` and other variations same error

Thank you!

Comment: Let's see if this is correct. The field in Table2 is a uniqueidentifier. The field in Table1 is a varchar(40). You want to take the uniqueidentifier, convert it to varchar, remove the dashes, then save it in Table1. To do that, you need to CAST / CONVERT the GUID into a varchar before using REPLACE().  **NOTE** If you are trying to store the converted GUID into a uniqueidentifier field in Table1 - you can't do that. uniqueidentifier is a numeric value, not a character string.

Comment: `If you are trying to store the converted GUID into a uniqueidentifier field in Table1 - you can't do that` Basically this. If you want to strip the dashes, your "GUID" in table1 needs to be some sort of char type (e.g. char(32)).

Comment: Both fields in each table are uniqueidentifier data type. Is there anyway to save it the format of table1

Comment: Sorry title is a bit misleading but it all started with table2 having the guid in the correct format but varchar .. when trying to update and convert got the error. Finally created another field in the same table as uniqueidentifier and used this code to update from the varchar field.     
        SUBSTRING(@uuid, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 13, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@uuid, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 21, 12)
        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and create [Guid] With data type NVarchar(36)

---

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##Temp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Temp1

CREATE TABLE ##Temp1 (
    Id INT identity
    ,Gid NVARCHAR(36)
    )

INSERT INTO ##Temp1 (Gid)
SELECT NEWID()

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ##Temp1
        WHERE CHARINDEX('-', Gid) > 0
        )
BEGIN
    UPDATE T2
    SET Gid = REPLACE(T3.Gid, '-', '')
    FROM ##Temp1 t2
    INNER JOIN ##Temp1 AS T3 ON T3.Id = t2.Id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No record contains with symbol ''-'''
END

SELECT * FROM ##Temp1
```